# How do not reload objects in code behind page ASP.NET C# on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple button:

```
<asp:Button ID="mybtn" runat="server" Text="My Btn"  onclick="mybtn_Click" />
```

And code behind:

```
protected MyCustomObject myObject;

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    this.myObject = new MyCustomObject();
  }
}

protected void mybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.myObject.step(1);
}

protected void anotherbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.myObject.step(2);
}
```

**The problem**: when click, the Page_Load is called and this.myObject is null.

The goal is to call anotherbtn_Click after call mybtn_Click with the same object instance.

**How to keep object's context?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assume that an instance of the Page class is kept for each "user"; therefore you can not use class variables as in your example. In order to store information across multiple requests, you can use the `Session Context`. See the following link for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

In your case you could store the `MyCustomObject` instance in the session state. Example

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    Session["MyObject"] = new MyCustomObject();
  }
}

protected void mybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyCustomObject myObject = Session["MyObject"] as MyCustomObject;
  myObject.step(1);
}

protected void anotherbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyCustomObject myObject = Session["MyObject"] as MyCustomObject;
  myObject.step(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`The web is stateless`. You always needs to create a new object for every request/post.

This means when every time your page is accessed , the new page instance will be created and served for it.

There are few ways you can solve your problem by using `Session` or serialize the object and keep it in `ViewState`

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
   this.myObject = new MyCustomObject();
   Sesssion["oldObject"]=this.myObject;
 }

protected void mybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if(session["oldObject"]!=null)
       {
        this.myObject=session["oldObject"] as MyCustomObject;
        this.myObject.step(1);
       }
}

protected void anotherbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(session["oldObject"]!=null)
   {
    this.myObject=session["oldObject"] as MyCustomObject;
    this.myObject.step(2);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.myObject` is null because you explicitly do *not* recreate it in `Page_Load` on postback.

Depending on your needs, you can either

- remove the `if (!IsPostBack)` check so that a new instance is created on each load; or
- put the instance in the session after it is created if you need to keep the same instance around between postbacks.